# Required crystal frequency for MCP2515 with ATmega328P

Tags: crystal, can, atmega328p

I want to connect a number of ATmega328P microcontrollers over a CAN bus. I found out that I will need some MCP2515 and MCP2551 ICs. In different schemas I sometimes see a 8 MHz crystal on the MCP2515 and sometimes a 16 MHz crystal.

This is the desired setup:

Multiple ATmega328P chips for a home automation project. The amount of data to be sent is really limited: switch on relay, switch off relay... so the speed on the CAN bus can be low.

What frequency should I take? Or doesn't it matter? Do I need to specify anything else needed to make the decision?

Is the use of a crystal on the ATmega required? Or can I use the internal clock of 8 MHz or 16 MHz?

Comment: @Lundlin Nothing wrong with the 328, but just not the correct choice here. And it's almost certainly because they're using Arduino.

Comment: @awjlogan It's a horrible 8-bit microcontroller from the stone age. Today everyone programs in C, not assembler, and programming 8-bit microcontrollers in C is both dangerous and painful. It is not a task for beginners, they should program 32 bit MCUs, which is multiple times easier, as you avoid numerous classic pitfalls.

Comment: can you advice an alternative in the same price class (few euro's | dollars)?

Comment: @Lundin That's a rather myopic viewpoint. Nothing wrong with 8bit micros or programming them in C. It's certainly more dangerous/painful to program them in ASM, especially for the beginner.

Comment: @mvermand Generally you will not get recommendations here - it's up to you, because your requirements are known only to you. I suggest starting at the Parametric Search page on a microcontroller vendor's website.

Comment: @awjlogan a simple little home automation project is getting way more complex than expected... started at simple wires - too much wires - went to I2C - no good for long distance - getting to CAN... too little experience... hoped just to get an easy "xxMHz will do" ;-)  => all same ATmega328P µC's + MCP2515 + MCP2551... isn't there a simple "xxMHz will do just fine" answer ;-)... strong in coding... very rusty in electronics... M

Comment: @awjlogan Anything ARM Cortex M0 with CAN. There's lots to pick from: NXP, ST, Renesas etc.

Comment: @awjlogan There's plenty wrong with 8 bit microcontrollers: performance, crap architectures and instruction sets, the C language loving to implicitly promote everything to 16 bit signed, banked memory when you go beyond 64kb etc etc. AVR stands out as particularly dysfunctional with the Harvard crap. On top of that we have the flood of beginners who pick up the harmful Arduino platform without a clue what they are doing. It can only end badly. There's really no excuse for using 8 bitters in the year 2018.

Comment: And yeah, writing a CAN driver is a rather complex thing to do. The easiest thing here would simply be to find any ARM with the complete CAN driver pre-made. Then buy some evaluation board with CAN transceivers and oscillators in place. Then you don't have to worry about a thing except the application itself.

Comment: @Lundlin Those things are mostly irrelevant as performance = enough to do the job, given other constraints (cost etc). Why use a more capable [expensive] chip than you need? If you've got a 64 kB program you should move up to a different architecture; 1 kB, why bother? Arduino-ificiation is a separate issue, but what's harmful about, say, an artist (not a programmer/hardware person and with no desire to be) using it for an installation? There's nothing inherently 'wrong' with 8 bit micros: they have strengths and limitations, much like any processor.

Comment: @mvermand Take Lundlin's advice and pick up some development boards if you're a software person, everything's ready to go :) The problem with recommending if that you might want X amount of memory, Y power consumption, the part might not be available to you etc...

Comment: you will find good useful information here: https://forum.arduino.cc/t/how-to-set-the-mhz-in-mcp2515-library-file-based-on-crystal-oscillator/628822/4

Answer (score 1):

The clock frequency must be picked so that it suits the divisor hardware of the CAN controller. What's suitable is different from controller to controller, but often the clock depends on how many time quanta you use per baud rate. You should aim to use one of the CANopen standardized baud rates and sample points, since these are industry standard (like 250 kbps or 125 kbps). The standard is available for free somewhere at https://www.can-cia.org if you register and download.

When you have determined how many time quanta that's needed to achieve a certain baud rate, you should pick a clock that gives a divisor error of less than 1%. CAN is picky with this: inaccurate divisors may cause the whole node to fail. Therefore you must always use crystal oscillators for CAN communication; built-in RC oscillators are too bad to be used.

Comment: Some vendors (unfortunately) use 0.5% ceramic oscillators (even though 0.1% ones are nearly the same price).

Comment: @PeterMortensen I believe that 0.5% should be sufficient for CAN, although cost is not really much of a reason to use an external ceramic resonator over a crystal.

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually **read the datasheet**.  After you do, the answers to your questions will be obvious.

Table 13-2, *Oscillator Timing Characteristics*, on page 71 tells you the min and max allowable frequencies outright.  If you could be running the part anywhere within its valid supply range, then those limits are 1 to 25 MHz.

There is also a whole chapter, section 8.0, page 53, about the oscillator.  I'm not going to read it for you.

The only remaining question is then what frequency you *want* to use within the allowable limits.  Again, the datasheet describes exactly how the oscillator frequency is used to derive the CAN bit timing.  In fact, there's a whole chapter on that too.  See section 5.0, *Bit Timing*, on page 37.  **Read it**.

Basically, you pick a oscillator frequency that can be divided down to the bit time quanta you want to use.  The number of quanta per bit is something you have some leeway over.  Generally you want to be in the 9 to 20 quanta per bit range if I remember right.